# Magento, Magmi API Update existing products?

Tags: php, api, magento, e-commerce, magmi

Currently using Magento API, however as we all know it's slow. Everyone says to use Magmi.

Well currently here's our situation. Twice a day we update from a csv file.

We update all matching products price/quantity
If product exists in csv, but not magento we import it as a new product
If product exists in magento, but not csv we set it to disabled.

Looking at the Magmi datapump API, I don't see a way to update existing products? Is there a way to update existing products via the datapump api? I only see a way to import new products. Also is there a way to mark products not in the csv, disabled in magento with Magmi?

Magmi_DataPumpFactory::getDataPumpInstance("productimport");

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? Even switching to update, nothing that the API actually updates works. Creating new products works fine for me, but when updating existing ones, none of my changes actually happen.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to the beginImportSession() method allows you to specify 'create' or 'update' mode.

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Magmi_Datapump_API